# How to parsing xml file with different elements using xml.sax python?

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm looking to parse large xml file using python. The file contains of several different elements. Here is an example of the files that I'm working on:

```
<movie title="Searching">
   <type>War, Thriller</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>2018</year>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>10</stars>
   <description>Missing girl</description>
</movie>
<song title="Need You Now">
   <type>Pop, Country</type>
   <format>MP4</format>
   <year>2010</year>
   <singer>Lady Antebellum</rating>
   <stars>8</stars>
</song>
   <movie title="Sidewalk of New York">
   <type>Romantic comedy</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>7</stars>
   <description>Stories of people's perspective of love in NY</description>
</movie>
```

From the files above, I want to parse and store all the information related to movie and song element to list. I am using xml.sax library and I ran into a problem on how to differentiate the element. For example, if I parse the type, format, and year tags it can't differentiate whether it belongs to movie or song. This is a snippet of code I use so far:

```
import psycopg2
import xml.sax
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

class MovieHandler( xml.sax.ContentHandler ):
   def __init__(self):
      self.CurrentData = ""
      self.type = ""
      self.format = ""
      self.year = ""
      self.data = {} #dict
      self.list = [] #list to store information
      self.list2 = []
      self.list3 = []
      self.list4 = []
      self.list5 = []

   # Call when an element starts
   def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
      self.CurrentData = tag
      if tag == "movie":
         title = attributes["title"]
         self.list.append(title)
         self.data['title'] = self.list
      elif tag == "song":
         title = attributes ["title"]
         self.list2.append(title)
         self.data['song_title'] = self.list2

   # Call when an elements ends
   def endElement(self, tag):
      if self.CurrentData == "type":
         type = self.type
         self.list3.append(type)
         self.data['type'] = self.list3
      elif self.CurrentData == "format":
         format = self.format
         self.list4.append(format)
         self.data['format'] = self.list4
      elif self.CurrentData == "year":
         year = int(self.year)
         self.list5.append(year)
         self.data['year'] = self.list5
      self.CurrentData = ""

   # Call when a character is read
   def characters(self, content):
      if self.CurrentData == "type":
         self.type = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "format":
         self.format = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "year":
         self.year = content
```

The result of the above code is that the type, format, and year will be double counted. Here is sample of the output:

```
{'format': ['DVD', 'MP4', 'DVD'],
 'title': ['Searching', 'Need You Now', 'Sidewalk of New York'],
 'type': ['War, Thriller',
  'Pop, Country',
  'Romantic Comedy'],
 'year': [2018, 2010]}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the current type in `startElement` and then you can store the data accordingly in `endElement()`

```
def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
    if tag == "movie":
        self.currentEntryType = "movie"
    elif tag == "song":
        self.currentEntryType = "song"
    ...

def endElement(self, tag):
    if self.currentEntryType == "movie":
        ... # store as movie data
```

(I am not really sure what your output list should look like, maybe you could post the perfect output list for the example xml)

Edit:
Would it be better to have 2 dicts, one for movies and one for songs? This depends on how your database looks like.

I am not sure why you want lists at all, wouldn't it be better to use a list of dicts instead of a dict of lists?

Using 2 dicts for example like this:

```
{   
'format': ['DVD', 'DVD'],
'title': ['Searching', 'Sidewalk of New York'],
'type': ['War, Thriller', 'Romantic Comedy'],
'year': [2018]
}
{   
'format': ['MP4'],
'title': ['Need You Now'],
'type': ['Pop, Country'],
'year': [2010]
}
```

The thing with this is that you cannot decide whether the year 2018 belongs to *Searching* or to *Sidewalk of New York*. Would that be a problem when you commit the list to your database?

Here's a solution with two dicts, one for movies, one for songs.
Basically it uses 8 lists instead of your 5 to store everything seperately.

```
class MovieHandler( xml.sax.ContentHandler ):
   def __init__(self):
      self.CurrentData = ""
      self.type = ""
      self.format = ""
      self.year = ""
      self.dataMovies = {} #dict
      self.dataSongs = {}
      self.list = [] # movie title
      self.list2 = [] # song title
      self.list3 = [] # movie type
      self.list4 = [] # movie format
      self.list5 = [] # movie year
      self.list6 = [] # song type
      self.list7 = [] # song format
      self.list8 = [] # song year

      self.currentEntryType = None

   # Call when an element starts
   def startElement(self, tag, attributes):
      self.CurrentData = tag
      if tag == "movie":
         title = attributes["title"]
         self.list.append(title)
         self.dataMovies['title'] = self.list
         self.currentEntryType = "movie"
      elif tag == "song":
         title = attributes ["title"]
         self.list2.append(title)
         self.dataSongs['song_title'] = self.list2
         self.currentEntryType = "song"

   # Call when an elements ends
   def endElement(self, tag):

      if tag == "movie":
         # Make movie lists the same length
         self.list3.extend([None]*(len(self.list)-len(self.list3)))
         self.list4.extend([None]*(len(self.list)-len(self.list4)))
         self.list5.extend([None]*(len(self.list)-len(self.list5)))   
      elif tag == "song":
         # Make movie lists the same length
         self.list6.extend([None]*(len(self.list2)-len(self.list6)))
         self.list7.extend([None]*(len(self.list2)-len(self.list7)))
         self.list8.extend([None]*(len(self.list2)-len(self.list8))) 

      if self.currentEntryType == "movie":
         if self.CurrentData == "type":
            type = self.type
            self.list3.append(type)
            self.dataMovies['type'] = self.list3
         elif self.CurrentData == "format":
            format = self.format
            self.list4.append(format)
            self.dataMovies['format'] = self.list4
         elif self.CurrentData == "year":
            year = int(self.year)
            self.list5.append(year)
            self.dataMovies['year'] = self.list5
         self.CurrentData = ""
      elif self.currentEntryType == "song":
         if self.CurrentData == "type":
            type = self.type
            self.list6.append(type)
            self.dataSongs['type'] = self.list6
         elif self.CurrentData == "format":
            format = self.format
            self.list7.append(format)
            self.dataSongs['format'] = self.list7
         elif self.CurrentData == "year":
            year = int(self.year)
            self.list8.append(year)
            self.dataSongs['year'] = self.list8
         self.CurrentData = ""

   # Call when a character is read
   def characters(self, content):
      if self.CurrentData == "type":
         self.type = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "format":
         self.format = content
      elif self.CurrentData == "year":
         self.year = content
```

Comment: I edited the post and can you give more explanation on that? thanks!

Comment: Could you also post how the output should look like

Comment: The output should be a dictionary of list of the elements (l edited the post).The idea is that from this dictionary, I want to insert it to postgres database. That's why I was thinking of storing it all to a dictionary first and with psycopg2 connect it to postgres. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what the problem with the output is? What should be different?

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant to be different is that how can I differentiate which type, format, or year in the list belongs to a movie or a song?

Comment: Thanks @Ven Ify that sounds like a better idea and I tried to create two dicts. However, when I tried that, the type, year, format only populate the first dict

Comment: I edited my answer, I added a second dict and also 3 lists to store the data  in separate lists

Comment: It works! Thanks! I have a follow up questions on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436197/psycopg2-how-to-include-null-values-in-inserting-dictionary-of-list-to-table if you might be able to help too. I've been having trouble inserting null values to postgres table using psycopg2

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer and added the None values. Changes are under the `endElement()` method. It just adds as many `None` values as missing entries: The difference `len(self.list)-len(self.list3)` is the number of `None` values that are added to list3