# Psycopg2 - How to include 'Null' values in inserting dictionary of list to table in postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, null, psycopg2, insert-into

I'm parsing my xml files and store them to a dictionary of list, where I will insert them into table at posgres using psycopg2. However, not all rows got inserted in the tables (it only inserted to the lowest number of values in the list). Here is the snippet of the dictionary of list:

```
dict_songs = {'title' : ['Need You Now', 'GTFO'...], 'format': ['MP4', 'MP3'...], 'type' : ['Country Pop', 'R&B Pop'..], 'year': [2010,2018..]}

dict_movie = {'title' : ['Searching', 'Sidewalk of New York'...], 'format': ['DVD', 'Blue Ray'...], 'type' : ['Thriller', 'Romcom'..], 'year': [2018..]
```

When I counted the length of each list in the dictionary it come up that not all the list has the same length, for example:

```
for key, value in dict_songs.items():
    #print value
    print(key, len([item for item in value if item]))

# The result is:
title 300000
format 189700
type 227294
year 227094
```

Title would be the primary key in the song table. When I inserted this dictionary to postgres it only shows 189700 records and not 300000. I want it to be 300000 and put Null for the null (none) values. The same goes to dict_movie

This is the code I use to insert the dict list into table:

```
keys = ['title', 'format', 'type','year']
insert_statement = 'insert into song_table (%s) values %s'
for t in zip(*(dict_songs[key] for key in keys)):
   cur.execute(insert_statement3, (AsIs(','.join(keys)),t))
myConnection.commit()
```

Any ideas why or how to go about this? Thank you!

Comment: Does the parsed XML have to be represented as a dictionary of lists? If you were able to get that as a list of small dictionaries, one for each record, it seems like handling nulls would then be trivial.

Comment: Not really, this is just the solution I had so far. So it would be better to have list of small dicts? Can you give me example on how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you don't know where the None/NULL values are.
Imagine these to lists:

```python
dict_songs = {
  'title' : ['Need You Now', 'GTFO', 'Titletest']
  'type' : ['Country Pop', 'R&B Pop']
}
```

Your table could have NULL values in three positions and there is no data in the lists that could hint to the correct one:

```sql
+ -------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| title        | type        | type        | type        |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Need You Now | Country Pop | Country Pop | NULL        |
| GTFO         | R&B Pop     | NULL        | Country Pop |
| Jinglebells  | NULL        | R&B Pop     | R&B Pop     |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

You lists need to have *None* values, so you know where to put *NULL* into the database table. Like this:

```python
dict_songs = {
  'title' : ['Need You Now', 'GTFO', 'Titletest']
  'type' : ['Country Pop', None, 'R&B Pop']
}
```

Comment: So should I check in every iteration if it's null values or not?

Comment: You need to make sure that you add `None` values when you convert the XML data to lists. The lists must have `None` values at the correct position (I added an example list to my answer).

Comment: If the list comes from parsing xml files, how to include that None values in the code?